¿Se puede hacer DATEDIFF que tome el viernes como el dia final de la semana, siendo que el Lunes es el inicial?
Tengo esta query de SQL Server, es bastante sencilla, como podrán apreciar, pero lo que se busca es que cada viernes realmente sea el conteo de la semana y no el lunes (único día donde se pueden hacer los registros, digo eso es algo de C# ya arreglé), como lo hace la Query que tengo aquí.
El problema es que las actualizaciones las quieren el viernes y no el lunes, es decir, que el primer conteo lo haga el viernes (5 días) y los posteriores el viernes de nuevo, ¿Alguna idea de cómo puedo hacerlo?
SELECT (DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(FechaInicio AS DATE), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))/7) AS 'Semanas transcurridas' FROM [CajaDeAhorroProcesada]


¿Que quieren contar exactamente? ¿Esa es una columna para agrupar y quieres que siempre muestre el viernes para contar?

La explicación realmente no deja claro que es lo que buscas para quienes no conocemos el tema del que hablas. Creo que vendría bien un ejemplo de los datos de entrada que hay en la tabla y qué resultado esperas obtener con dichos datos. Sobre todo, tomando en cuenta que DateDiff simplemente devuelve la diferencia entre dos fechas, sin importar qué día de la semana era en cada una, o en las intermedias.
